# hadoop MapReduce sort by value only

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way to sort the MapReduce output by value only, and without changing the output sequence of key and value?

the original output is like (sorted by key):

```
A 1

B 2

C 1

D 3
```

and I need the output like this (sorted by value):

```
D 3

B 2

A 1

C 1
```

I tried to make it by adding  another sorting job using `Inversemapper` to swap the key and value so that the output is sorted by value, it worked, however the output is like:

```
3 D

2 B

1 A

1 C
```

Is there anyway to reverse the output format of key and value?

or is there any other way to sort by value only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom value and implement WritableComparable interface to implement the compareTo() or you can inherit the WritableComparator class to override the compare() method. Choice is yours. Given below is the customized key and customised value class
**CustKey.java**

```
package in.aniruddha.mapreduce.custFormat;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class CustKey implements Writable {
    protected Text customerId;
    //default constructor
    public CustKey()
    {
        super();
        customerId=new Text();
    }
    public CustKey(Text customerId)
    {
        super();
        this.customerId=customerId;
    }
    public CustKey(String customerId)
    {
        super();
        this.customerId=new Text(customerId);
    }
    public CustKey(CustKey k)
    {
        super();
        this.customerId=k.customerId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the customerId
     */
    public Text getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    /**
     * @param customerId the customerId to set
     */
    public void setCustomerId(Text customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = new Text(customerId);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.customerId.readFields(arg0);
    }


    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.customerId.write(arg0);
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((customerId == null) ? 0 : customerId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CustKey other = (CustKey) obj;
        if (customerId == null) {
            if (other.customerId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!customerId.equals(other.customerId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Similarly Custom value format
**CustValue.java**

```
package in.aniruddha.mapreduce.custFormat;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class CustValue implements WritableComparable<CustValue> {
    protected CustKey custId;
    protected Text firstName,lastName,age,profession;
    public CustValue()
    {
        super();
        custId=new CustKey();
        firstName=new Text();
        lastName=new Text();
        age=new Text();
        profession=new Text();
    }

    public CustValue(CustKey custId, Text firstName, Text lastName, Text age,
            Text profession) {
        super();
        this.custId = new CustKey(custId);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.profession = profession;
    }
    public CustValue(String custId, String firstName, String lastName, String age,
            String profession) {
        super();
        this.custId = new CustKey(custId);
        this.firstName = new Text(firstName);
        this.lastName =new Text(lastName);
        this.age = new Text(age);
        this.profession = new Text(profession);
    }
    /**
     * @return the custId
     */
    public CustKey getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    /**
     * @param custId the custId to set
     */
    public void setCustId(CustKey custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public Text getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(Text firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public Text getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(Text lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public Text getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(Text age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * @return the profession
     */
    public Text getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    /**
     * @param profession the profession to set
     */
    public void setProfession(Text profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.custId.readFields(arg0);
        this.age.readFields(arg0);
        this.profession.readFields(arg0);
        this.lastName.readFields(arg0);
        this.firstName.readFields(arg0);
        }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.custId.write(arg0);
        this.age.write(arg0);
        this.profession.write(arg0);
        this.lastName.write(arg0);
        this.firstName.write(arg0);
        }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CustValue o) {
        /*
         * Here we're gonna compare customerid and the age
         */
        int comp=this.custId.customerId.compareTo(o.custId.customerId);
        if(comp!=0)
        {
            return comp;
        }
        else return this.age.compareTo(o.age);
    }

}
```

Here, if you don't want to sort the keys but values then implement WritableComparable in the custom Value class only and and since you want the keys to be sorted according to the values, The Key has to implement the Writable interface.

---

Please get back to me if you face doubts. Thankyou :)

Comment: This is helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

M/R is always sort-by-key. If you want to sort by value then you need to create another job that maps the value to be sorted into the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Secondary sort to sort based on values.Define composite key and override SortComparator to sort based on values.This will provide sorted values within a reducer.

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't do what you think it does. You can certainly sort values within a common key range (secondary sorting) but if the comparator ignores the key then you'll end up with all values being routed to the same reducer during the shuffle/sort phase.

Comment: You are right.Thanks for noticing it.I missed the point that secondary sort is for sorting values within a key.It will require an additional job to produce sorted output.If the requirement is not to produce globally sorted values,the Inversemapper  logic can be modified to emit output in required format.